# C/C++ equivalent to java Integer.toHexString

Tags: java, c++, c, integer, porting

C/C++ equivalent to java Integer.toHexString.

Porting some code from java to C/C++, does C have a build in function to Integer.toHexString in java?

UPDATE:

Heres is the exact code i'm trying to port:

```
String downsize = Integer.toHexString(decimal);
```

Comment: Which is it, C or C++? The answers will be different.

Comment: C++, intended to be used with the iPhone.

Answer (score 9):

Using the `<sstream>` header:

```
std::string intToHexString(int i) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << std::showbase << i;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In C:

`sprintf(s, "%x", value);`

Be sure to have enough space at `s` for rendering of the hex number. 64 bytes are guaranteed (hereby) to be enough.

Comment: You should use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` because the latter can overflow the buffer.

Comment: In case your compiler supports it. MSVC still doesn't support C99, afaik.

Comment: Microsoft has their own solution (StrSafe).  If you're dealing with `TCHAR`s that's probably the way to go.  If, on the other hand, you actually know whether you're dealing with `char`s or `wchar_t`s (and, by extension, the encoding you're using) then you can use something more standardized.

Answer (score 5):

How about [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/format/index.html) for a C++ solution:

```
(format("%X") % num).str()
```

Answer (score 3):

`char s[1+2*sizeof x]; sprintf(s, "%x", x);`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss(std::stringstream::out);
int i;
ss << std::hex << i << flush;
string converted = ss.str();
```

Also take a look at [setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/) (which needs `#include <iomanip>`)

Answer (score 0):

itoa does what you want (third param denotes base):

```
/* itoa example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  int i = 12;
  char buffer [33];
  itoa (i,buffer,16);
  printf ("hexadecimal: %s\n",buffer);
  return 0;
}
```